# Can one talk "with" someone?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

The verb *talk* usually has *to* preceding its complement/object:

(I) I talked to him about his misbehavior.

Is it idiomatic (and/or grammatical) to use *with* instead?

(II) I talked with him about his misbehavior. (?)

(III) Who did you talk with yesterday?  (?)

I ask because an associate has claimed that *with* is not idiomatic with *talk* and therefore ungrammatical.

This [online resource](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic19865.html) suggests the difference is semantic:

> Usage varies, but generally 'talk to' indicates the simple action (as
>   opposed to remaining silent), while 'talk with' suggests an extended
>   conversation.

Comment: Americans, who use prepositions completely differently to us, talk *with* people all the time. In Britain we generally *talk to* our interlocutors, and they talk to us. In Britain 'talking with someone' implies you are both speaking at the same time, a bit like singing a duet.

Comment: The reason ***with*** is more strongly associated with an *extended* conversation is simply that (superficially, at least) you might ***talk to*** someone without actually engaging in a two-way conversation. Monologues excepted, two-way conversations are likely to be longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that **talk** collocates naturally with both **to** and **with** and that both **talk to** and **talk with** are grammatical.

Your recent edit of your question actually provides the semantic difference:

**talk to** indicates the activity of talking, followed by the listener as object

**talk with** implies conversation, discussion, and discursiveness

Some examples (with comments) appearing on different online dictionaries (most of which don't provide an explanation of the distinction):

> a. Everyone was busily talking with their friends.
>
> b. I need to talk to you.
>
> c. Talk with your advisor.
>
> d. It was no use talking to Anthony.

a. clearly connotes discussion

b. sounds might sound a bit stern, or as though the speaker will do most of the speaking, perhaps to inform the listener of bad news or admonish him/her

c. clearly connotes discussion

d. suggests Anthony doesn't listen, not just that Anthony doesn't like to converse

Is the distinction hard and fast? To my ear:

a. needs "with," not "to"

b. could use either

c. could use either, but better with "with"

d. could use either, but there may be a slight connotative difference

Answer (score 1):

Americans, who use prepositions completely differently to us, ***talk with*** people all the time.

In Britain we generally ***talk to*** our interlocutors, and they talk to us.

'Talking with someone' always sounds to me as though you are both speaking at the same time, a bit like singing a duet.

Comment: Google Books isn't always a good way of identifying a transatlantic usage divide, but I can't see much difference between [the US chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talked+with+him%2Ctalked+to+him&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalked%20with%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalked%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0) and [the UK one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talked+with+him%2Ctalked+to+him&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalked%20with%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalked%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FumbleFingers which just serves to emphasise, in my mind, that those things are not worth the paperless screen on which they appear. It recently emerged when someone did some checking that the UK usage included American editions of books written in the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But whoever is saying it is not using correct English are they. One can *converse with*, one can *consult with*, and one can *discuss with*, but one *speaks to*. I am troubled by the idea that English can be 'changed' simply because people simply don't know how to speak it.

Comment: @WS2: Why be troubled? Language change is inevitable and unstoppable.

Comment: @WS2: I have no interest in fashion, and therefore no interest in "correct". But when I read "talk with" in a sentence I generally conclude that the writer was American (or for an American audience, or ... ). It would be grammatical, but unidiomatic for me to say it.

Comment: Choose your favourite British newspaper and enter "talk with" in the search bar. This will turn up many results (and not just in quotations of poorly-bred Yankees). Will you say the writers are running afoul of British English?

Comment: I didn't say "good" at all. As to why... For an enormous variety of reasons beyond learning "proper" English. Don't get me wrong; I correct my kids English all the time. And they sometimes tell me I sound like a fuddy-duddy. :) at the end of they day, I find it useful to be proficient in several dialects.

Comment: @RustyTuba I did that with The Guardian, and you are right - quite a lot come up. But what was noticeable was they were mostly instances where 'talk' was being used as a noun. It is one thing to say 'Obama in a talk with Putin said...'. 'It is another to say John talked with Jane last night'. I didn't notice very many of the latter. There are also a lot of instances of 'talk to'. But my wider point has always been that if you think good English is simply what people speak, then why do you send children to school? Why bother to ederficate 'em?

Comment: @RustyTuba Glad that you accept that there is a right way and a wrong way to speak English.

Comment: I didn't say that either. Just want them to know several dialects, one if which you call "correct."

Comment: @RustyTuba I sense that you also have a 'correct' form to which you adhere. But I have had this argument, endlessly, with the powers-that-be of this site. I call that which I strive to speak Received English, to correspond with the Received Pronunciation. Linguistics scholars object to this term, as they do to The Queen's English. But one has to call it something. In my case it is my grandchildren whom I correct. and whilst I correct their grammar and vocabulary, I celebrate the local accents that they use.

Comment: Well, let's not argue endlessly here. But best of luck!